# I recently converted my ex HDD from FAT32 to NTFS. now my pc doesn't find or pick up my NTFS HDD

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, external-hard-drive

I recently converted my external hard drive from FAT32 to NTFS using the Command Prompt.  Everything was working fine, I copied a 7GB file to it and everything worked. The next day I switched on my PC, I couldn't and still can't find my external 1.5TB hard drive by my computer.

I have about 500 to 800 GB of data on it that I really don't want to lose. Its a Iomega Seagate Freeagent HDD. Has no switch, it switched on automatically, don't know if that helps.

Comment: It is visible in the Disk Management console?

Answer (score 2):

Contol Panel -> Admin tools -> Comp management -> Disk management.

Bind the NTFS partition to a "drive letter" there.